# Keeping track of the completions in a repeating sequence in Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Could you please let me know if there's a way of keeping track of the completion of the current repetition in a repeating sequence? My end goal is to keep track of the current count and rate of completed repetitions which I can do once I have the base. Thank you for your help.

```
sequence.Repeat().Publish().RefCount()
```

I would like to capture the completions of "sequence" in the structure above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Materialize` to convert your observable of `T` into an observable of `Notification<T>`. This allows you to handle values, completion and error just like ordinary sequence values. You may then just filter out the completions. However, I did not quite understand what you intend to do with them...

```
var completions = sequence
    .Materialize()
    .Where(notification => notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnCompleted)
    .Repeat();
```

Comment: Thank you. "Sequence" is a resilient quotes stream and I want to keep track of how often it gets disconnected, so I can disable live trading if the rate of disconnects exceeds my threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is valid, although it'll hide the stream errors, and I'd not sure it's what you wanted.
Alternatively you can simply concat your stream with a single-element-stream before repeat, and that special element will be your completion marker:

```
var completions = sequence
    .Concat(Observable.Return(42))
    .Repeat().Publish().RefCount();
```

If you need this element to have some context (your question doesn't say), combien it with `Observable.Defer`:

```
var completions = sequence
    .Concat(Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return(someExpression))
    .Repeat().Publish().RefCount();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to come up with a solution using Concat and the Obervable.Empty but did not think monitoring for a special completion marker.